# printing values and keys from a dictionary in a specific format (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have this dictionary (name and grade):

```
d1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

and I have to print it like this:

```
|a          | 1          |       C |
|b          | 2          |       B |
|c          | 3          |       A |
```

I created a new dictionary to find out the letter grading based on these conditions:

```
d2 = {}
d2 = d1
for (key, i) in d2.items():
    if i = 1:
        d2[key] = 'A'
    elif i = 2:
        d2[key] = 'B'
    elif i = 3:
        d2[key] = 'C'
```

When trying to print it using the following code:

```
sorted_d = sorted(d)

format_str = '{:10s} | {:10f} | {:>7.2s} |'
for name in sorted_d:
    print(format_str.format(name, d[name]))
```

It prints:

```
a         | 1         |
b         | 2         |
c         | 3         |
```

How can I add the letter grade?

Comment: Your grade code is not exactly altering the right dictionary. It is referencing `d1` (not copying it). You then alter `dw`. You also *inverted the grades*; your sample output claims `1` should be `C` but then you actually used `A` for `1`.

Comment: Your claimed output also doesn't match your actual code.

Comment: You are also sorting a dictionary `d`, but your *input dictionary* is called `d1`. Can you please at least produce code in your question that would actually reproduce your problem correctly?

Comment: Your sample code for the output also throws an exception (`IndexError: tuple index out of range`) because you didn't provide 3 arguments for the 3 format slots. And `{:10f}` would produce `1.000000`, `2.000000` and `3.000000` for the `d[name]` values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your grade dictionary can be created like:

```
grades = {1: 'C', 2: 'B', 3: 'A'}  # going by the sample output
```

`{:>7.2f}` would expect a *floating point number*. Just use `s` or leave of the type formatter, and don't specify a precision. Your dictionary values are integers, so I'd use the `d` format for those, not `f`. Your sample output also appears to *left align* those numbers, not right-align, so `'<10d'` would be needed for the format specifier.

To include the grade letters, look up the grades with `d[name]` as the key:

```
format_str = '{:10s} | {:<10d} | {:>10s} |'
for name in sorted_d:
    print(format_str.format(name, d[name], grades[d[name]]))
```

Demo:

```
>>> d1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
>>> grades = {1: 'C', 2: 'B', 3: 'A'}  # going by the sample output
>>> sorted_d = sorted(d1)
>>> format_str = '{:10s} | {:<10d} | {:>10s} |'
>>> for name in sorted_d:
...     print(format_str.format(name, d1[name], grades[d1[name]]))
... 
a          | 1          |          C |
b          | 2          |          B |
c          | 3          |          A |
```